# Can I add a dynamic key to an object?

Tags: javascript, object, key

What would a function look like that "keys" an input object? I've been researching the topic, but couldn't find any good answers.

So, if I have an input object...

```
var fruits = [{fruit: "apple", taste: "sour"},
              {fruit: "cherry", taste: "sweet", color: "red"}];


functionname(fruits, function(i) { return i.fruit; });

RETURN: 

   { "apple": [{fruit: "apple", taste: "sour"}],
   { "cherry": [{fruit: "cherry", taste: "sweet", color: "red"}]

functionname(fruits, function(i) { return i.taste.length; });

RETURN: 

   { "4": [{fruit: "apple", taste: "sour"}],
   { "5": [{fruit: "cherry", taste: "sweet", color: "red"}]
```

Comment: My initial thought was forEach, but forEach is   Array.forEach(callback),  so instead I would say is `[].forEach.call`  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function which creates a new object and return the items with the wanted key.

Version with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
function getKeyedArray(array, callback) {
    var object = Object.create(null);
    array.reduce(function (a) {
        var key = callback(a);
        object[key] = object[key] || [];
        object[key].push(a);
    });
    return object;
}

var fruits = [{ fruit: "apple", taste: "sour" }, { fruit: "cherry", taste: "sweet", color: "red" }];

console.log(getKeyedArray(fruits, function (i) { return i.fruit; }));
console.log(getKeyedArray(fruits, function (i) { return i.taste.length; }));
```

Version with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function getKeyedArray(array, callback) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var key = callback(a);
        r[key] = r[key] || [];
        r[key].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
}

var fruits = [{ fruit: "apple", taste: "sour" }, { fruit: "cherry", taste: "sweet", color: "red" }];

console.log(getKeyedArray(fruits, function (i) { return i.fruit; }));
console.log(getKeyedArray(fruits, function (i) { return i.taste.length; }));
```